# FindElementByXPath won't find elements off page

Tags: c#, appium, appium-android

I'm new to Appium but have some experience in Selenium, both using C# as I know the language.
I'm using a Pokedex app to learn Selenium and I have managed to get it to open the first 4 on the list. However, when I tried to get it to open the 5th the exact same way (where the object that I'm searching for is half off the screen) it comes back with `OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.`. I've spent a good amount of time trying to figure this out and looking up online etc, however I can't find anything.

```
AppiumDriver<AndroidElement> driver;
    [TestInitialize]
    public void OpenApp()
    {
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.SetCapability("noReset", "true");
        cap.SetCapability("device", "Android");
        cap.SetCapability("deviceName", "Galaxy S8");
        cap.SetCapability("platformVersion", "8.0.0");
        cap.SetCapability("platformName", "Android");
        cap.SetCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
        cap.SetCapability("appPackage", "com.goldex");
        cap.SetCapability("appActivity", "com.goldex.view.activity.MainActivity");
        driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void ViewBulbasaur()
    {
        // Arrange
        driver.FindElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text, 'Bulbasaur')]").Click();
        // Assert
        var objText = driver.FindElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text, 'Bulbasaur #001')]").Text;
        Assert.AreEqual("Bulbasaur #001", objText);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void ViewIvysaur()
    {
        //Arrange
        driver.FindElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text, 'Ivysaur')]").Click();
        // Assert
        var objText = driver.FindElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text, 'Ivysaur #002')]").Text;
        Assert.AreEqual("Ivysaur #002", objText);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void ViewVenusaur()
    {
        //Arrange
        driver.FindElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text, 'Venusaur')]").Click();
        // Assert
        var objText = driver.FindElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text, 'Venusaur #003')]").Text;
        Assert.AreEqual("Venusaur #003", objText);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void ViewMegaVenusaur()
    {
        //Arrange
        driver.FindElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text, 'Mega Venusaur')]").Click();
        // Assert
        var objText = driver.FindElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text, 'Mega Venusaur #003')]").Text;
        Assert.AreEqual("Mega Venusaur #003", objText);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void ViewCharmander()
    {
        //Arrange
        driver.FindElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text, 'Charmander')]").Click();
        // Assert
        var objText = driver.FindElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text, 'Charmander #004')]").Text;
        Assert.AreEqual("Charmander #004", objText);
    }
    [TestCleanup]
    public void CloseApp()
    {
        driver.CloseApp();
    }
```

The issue is with the Charmander one, the rest pass.

Comment: It turns out that Appium cannot detect any element that is off of the display, even if it is on the same page. You can get the page to scroll by using UiScrollable like this: `var locator = new ByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).setMaxSearchSwipes(350).getChildByText(new UiSelector().className(\"android.widget.TextView\"), \"Charmander\")");
            driver.FindElement(locator).Click();`. This will keep scrolling until it finds the element or it times out (60s). You are supposed to be able to add a capability to extend it, but doesn't work